# How to configure SSL socket for the javax.xml.ws.Service?

Tags: ssl, authentication, client, wsdl

I have a tomcat application that invokes an IIS hosted ssl enabled, client auth enabled Webservice

This Tomcat application talks to multiple wenservices and probably each of them require client auth along with PKI authentication.

For the IIS Webservice the wsdl url can change hence I use

javax.xml.ws.Service(url,qname) constructor by passing the url for the wsdl ...

The thing is I need to call the above with SSL with custom client key. How to I tell the above constructor to use a sslsocket that I create with my custom KeyManager ? I do not want to use 
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory as that will enforce other outgoing ssl connection to follow to my keymanager which is exclusive to the IIS webservice.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Isn't that the same as your previous question with more details? http://serverfault.com/q/349392/47187  (As I was suspecting when writing my answer there, this is becoming a question for StackOverflow: you could flag this question and ask to have it migrated.)

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the answer to [your similar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/349392/47187) and make sure that Tomcat's `<Connectors />` don't use the `javax.net.ssl` properties, setting your keystore for the default key manager might not be the end of the world. `HttpsURLConnection`s will only authenticate with it to server that ask for it (client-certificate authentication is always requested by the server) and that ask for a client-cert from a CA list that would match your certificate's issuer. This might not be such a big problem in practice.

If you think it's too big a problem, there seems to be an [undocumented property](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/developer/JAXWSProperties.java.html) called `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory`. Its documentation is as follows:

> Set this property on the BindingProvider.getRequestContext() to enable
>   HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory). The property
>   is set as follows:
>
> SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = ...; Map ctxt =
>   ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext();
>   ctxt.put(SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslFactory);
>
> THIS PROPERTY IS EXPERIMENTAL AND IS SUBJECT TO CHANGE WITHOUT NOTICE
>   IN FUTURE.